# Silent push with GPS

Tags: xcode, swift

Возможно ли, при получении Пуша запустить геолокацию и отправить месторасположение на сервер.

Comment: нет, нельзя....

Answer (score 1):

Ваше приложение не становится активным при получении пуша, только после того, как пользователь нажал на уведомление. Таким образом ваше приложение при получении пуша ничего сделать не может.

В iOS 10, кстати говоря, при получении пуша, он будет передаваться вашему приложению, для дополнительной кастомизации до того, как он показан пользователю. Возможно то, что вы хотите сделать будет возможно в ios10.